# AxiosError: Network Error on Android React Native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, axios, expo

I keep receiving the Axios Network Error while trying to do get request. Everything is working perfectly fine on iOS. Its only on android where this occurs. On the emulator I noticed when I can change the base url to include 10.0.2.2, it works, but not on the acutal device. Here is my current setup

base url is http://localhost:8888

```
 const fetchComponent = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("props received:", props.link);
      const configurationObject = {
        method: "get",
        url: props.link,
      };
      const response = await axios(configurationObject);

      console.log("response:", response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { data, loading };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the base url to point to the IP address of the device on which the server is running

For example, if the IP address of your device is `192.0.2.235`, then your base url should be `http://192.0.2.235:8888`

Comment: How to find the IP address of the server?

Comment: when you are starting the app on your computer using `npm start` or `yarn start`, you should use the computer IP address. In windows you can enter `ipconfig` in terminal and check your device `IPv4 Address`

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchComponent = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {

      console.log("props received:", props.link);
axios.get(`${props.link}`)
.then(data=>setData(data.data)
.catch(err=>setLoading(false))
  };

  return { data, loading };
};
```

try like this

Comment: I have tried the above code, and am still receiving the network error

Comment: were you able to solve it?